# Output variable value labels with margins, dydx()

Tags: stata

Is there a way to report the variable value labels instead of the default output from Stata's `margins` command when using the `dydx()` option?

For example, when using `margins`, without the `dydx()`, the output uses the value labels for `sex`:

```
clear
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/margex

regress y i.sex i.group
margins sex
```

However, when using `dydx()` the value labels are gone:

```
margins, dydx(sex) at(group = (1 2 3))
```

I could not find any option to set in `margins` that would force this.

It did not seem like *community-contributed* commands such as `esttab` would accomplish this either.

Cross-posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1523907-use-variable-value-labels-instead-of-%E2%80%9C1-at_1%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%9C1-at_2%E2%80%9D-from-margins-dydx).

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the `at()` option not `dydx()`.

The correct syntax is the following:

```
. margins, dydx(sex) at(1.group 2.group 3.group)  

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =      3,000
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : 1.sex
at           : 1.group         =    .3996667 (mean)
               2.group         =    .3726667 (mean)
               3.group         =    .2276667 (mean)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         sex |
     female  |   18.32202   .8930951    20.52   0.000     16.57088    20.07316
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```

Compare this with your syntax:

```
. margins, dydx(sex) at (group = (1 2 3))

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =      3,000
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : 1.sex

1._at        : group           =           1

2._at        : group           =           2

3._at        : group           =           3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.sex        |
         _at |
          1  |   18.32202   .8930951    20.52   0.000     16.57088    20.07316
          2  |   18.32202   .8930951    20.52   0.000     16.57088    20.07316
          3  |   18.32202   .8930951    20.52   0.000     16.57088    20.07316
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```